# MYSQL DB field change not showing on front end

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

There is one changing I am making directly on the mysql DB and for some reason that particular change successfully made on DB is NOT showing on the front end.

It is about changing the total number of days of a project to a new number.

I went on mysql and typed :

```
UPDATE projects set project_closed_at = '4' WHERE project_closed_at like '2';
```

The field that control the total number of days of a project got changed to **4** days instead of **2** BUT, on the front end it did not Change anything.

This is what We still see:

***1 day to go (Start date was 21st April and we are the 22nd)
End date 23 April.***

We should see:

***3 days to go (Start date was 21st April and we are the 22nd)
End date 25 April.***

When I do the test of modifying other fields of `Project` in the DB, all changes are taken into account on the DB and showing on front end. But changing the `project_closed_at` does not show on the front end though successfully changed on DB.

The data used in `project_closed_at`  is used here on the front end:

```
<% if @project.remaining_days.to_i >= 0 %> 
<%= @project.remaining_days.to_i %> 
<% else %> 
0 
<% end %>
```

and here `: @project.deadline.strftime("%B %d %Y")`

What am I missing?

thanks!

Comment: Try posting your full view.As per now i can't see where you using `project_closed_at` field in given code snippet.

Comment: Where you have used `project_closed_at` in the view? Is `@project.remaining_days` this the value of `project_closed_at`. Then show us your Model `Project`.

Comment: Hello guys, thanks to your comments...it helped my find the solution. Actually I had to look at an other value names "deadline" in the DB so I changed it and now that project the expected changes are working fine on the front end.